# ¿Hay diferencia entre "caldo" y "sopa"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Se me hace que refieren a la misma cosa, pero algunos me dicen que son distintas.  Formalmente, ¿hay alguna diferencia?  ¿O depende de la región?

Comment: Una curiosidad: _caldo_ deriva del latín _calidus_, "caliente". Y _sopa_ deriva del germánico _suppa_, "pan mojado". Es interesante ver cómo ambas palabras convergieron en sinónimos. Y su etimología nos permite tanto sospechar sus diferencias, como cuál es su relación con otras palabras y usos: "caldo de cultivo", "me estás caldeando", "sopaipillas", "un buen caldo" (hablando de vinos). Compara "escaldar" con "sopear".

Comment: @Rodrigo Un caso de una sopa en la acepción de "pan mojado" es, por ejemplo, el postre italiano, popular en Buenos Aires, llamado [_sopa inglesa_](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuppa_inglese), que consiste básicamente en capas de masa empapada en almíbar con alguna clase de vino e intercaladas con crema pastelera u otros dulces.

Comment: Sí. La sopa puede tener un montón de cosas, pero el caldo es solo caldo. Sopa = Caldo + ingredientes extra

Comment: Gastronomicamente hay muchas diferencias... un caldo se hace cociendo en agua carne, huesos o verduras y una vez cocido se retiran. En una sopa los ingredientes que la componen no se retiran. Además a menudo una sopa está hecha a base de caldo, en vez de agua.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El caldo es lo que obtienes al hervir algún alimento, comúnmente pollo, verduras, etc; la sopa tiene por lo general al caldo como ingrediente, y en su forma más básica es sólo un caldo con algún agregado, generalmente pan, sémola o fideos, aunque pueden ser mucho más complejas. También hay algunos platos a los que se llama caldos aunque estrictamente hablando sean sopas, como el español [caldo gallego](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldo_gallego) y el chileno [caldillo de congrio](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caldillo_de_congrio).  Las definiciones relevantes del DRAE para [caldo](http://dle.rae.es/caldo) y [sopa](http://dle.rae.es/sopa) dicen:

> **Sopa:**
>   2. f. Plato compuesto de rebanadas de pan, fécula, arroz, fideos u otras pastas, y el caldo de la olla u otro análogo en que se han
>   cocido.
>
> **Caldo:**
>    1. m. Líquido que resulta de cocer o aderezar algunos alimentos.

Por supuesto, el DRAE no es un manual de cocina pero básicamente dice lo correcto.

Comment: A menudo pienso en un Caldo como algo que puedes tomar en vaso, bebido, mientras que la Sopa la tomamos en plato, con cuchara.

Comment: Aunque en Chile preferimos decir _caldo_, también usamos como sinónimo la palabra _consomé_. Ambos, caldo y consomé, son o bien tipos de sopa, o bien ingredientes de una sopa.

Answer (score 1):

No es incorrecta la respuesta aceptada, pero quisiera ofrecer una distinción más sencilla y práctica:

El caldo puede ser el único plato de la comida, mientras que la sopa solo forma parte de la comida.

También me gustaría añadir que la sopa no tiene que ser líquida: en México, la *sopa seca* es pasta, por ejemplo espagueti, sin caldito.

(Por cierto, cuando algo suelta un juguito durante la cocción, el líquido que suelta puede llamarse *el caldito* o *su caldo*.  También se algo se cuece en agua, depués de la cocción el líquido que queda se puede llamar *caldo*.)

Answer (score 0):

Sí, sopa es caldo más otras cosas, por ejemplo: caldo más presas de pollo, más verduras, caldo más fideos, papá, choclo...
Caldo es el resultado del hervor de alguna carne. Es una base o sustancia.